# Maytag MED3500FW0 help with diagnosing no heat

Tags: electrical, dryer, relay

I have a hope that you'll be able to either confirm or refute my diagnosis. As a quick aside, I work in computer science and have a decent bit of electrical engineering experience, as well as practical experience working as an industrial electrician's apprentice during high school, so I'm not totally clueless on these topics.

I have a Maytag MED3500FW0 front loading dryer that I've had for about 4 or 5 years now. We've had absolutely no issues with it up to this point, it's been relatively perfect. However, as of late it hasn't been trying clothes, as it hasn't been producing heat. The diagnosis I've come to is that the main board itself is bad, I'll outline my reasoning below for people to (potentially/hopefully) find flaws in.

First, I looked in the technician service booklet and learned that I could put it in diagnostic mode. The code that I retrieved was F4E4, which the book says is low voltage on L2. I unplugged the dryer and verified that I had both legs at the outlet, I did.

Second, I took off the back panel where the cord goes in and verified that I had 120/240V (120 from L1 to neutral, 120 from L2 to neutral, and 235 from L1 to L2).

Next, I verified continuity across the high temp fuse, and combination switch part.

Next, I plugged everything back in and started the dryer. While running I verified I had L1 voltage (to neutral) going into and out of the centripetal switch, into and out of the heating element, into and out of the combination switch piece, into and out of the high temp cut-out, and going in to the L1 leg of the heater relay on the main board. I also tested at the board for L2 (to neutral) going in to the heater relay.

Finally, I tested across the L1 and L2 that were both present to neutral at the relay, and found 0 volts. The heater circuit relay is mounted on the board (board part number W11537223) and I believe it's possible to simply replace the relay, but want to make sure I didn't miss o mess up a troubleshooting step. Also, while the relay could be de-soldered and replaced, I would feel more comfortable replacing the whole board if this sounds like the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check the cycling thermostat?  Does the relay look burnt or do you see burnt components on the board?  https://paradiseapplianceservice.com/dryer-repair/how-to-repair-a-non-heating-maytag-dryer/